# LINQ To Entities - M to M selection returns more columns than needed

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following situation which, works fine:

```
IQueryable<Experiment> experiments1 = _db.Experiments.Where(e => e.Projects.Any(p => p.Id == project.Id));
IQueryable<Experiment> experiments2 = _db.Experiments.Where(e => e.Tools.Any(m => m.Project.Id == project.Id));
var experimentsList = experiments1.Union(experiments2).OrderBy(e => e.Date).Select(e => new
    {
    e.Id,
    e.Name,
     e.Date
    }).ToList();
```

Checking with SQL Profiles, this translates in 1 SQL query which correctly extract **Id**, **Name** and **Date** from the union.

The problem arises when I perform a join with a many-to-many connected table:

```
var experimentsList = experiments1.Union(experiments2).OrderBy(e => e.Date).Select(e => new
{
  e.Id,
  e.Name,
  e.Date,
  e.Types.Select(t => t.Name)
  // or also just e.Types
}).ToList();
```

The generated SQL query for some reasons not only return the "needed" columns but returns **all the columns in the Experiment table** + the additional specified columns (i.e. types' names).

This result in a pretty big loss in performances.

Btw, in the code I later need to perform:

```
experimentsList.Select(e => new
{
  e.Id,
  e.Name,
  e.Date,
  Types = string.Join(", ", e.Types)
})
```

So I need the faster way to have in memory Id, Name, Date + a list of types.

Thanks!

Comment: Removing `linq-to-sql`: that is a different LINQ provider to EF and will only confuse things.

Comment: Why are you using Any and not join?  I expect you want Join.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Column names may need to be changed

```
var result = from exp in _db.Experiments
join t in _db.Types on exp.TypeID = t.Id
select new
{
  exp.Id,
  exp.Name,
  exp.Date,
  t.Name
}).ToList();
```